# Adding bold to a UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, bold

I'm trying to figure out how to best bold and un-bold a UILabel with a font that was defined in the Interface Builder.

I know I can do this, for example:

```
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
```

But then I'm forcing the font to potentially different (both in style and size) than the way it was designed in IB.

I'm looking for something that essentially does this:

```
[myLabel setBold:TRUE];
```

or False, as the case may be.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what kind of font are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no real concept of "Bold" in UIKit.  If you ever try setting part of an attributed string to "Bold", you are actually selecting the bold font variant in the same font family.

You could so something semihackish like this:

```
@implementation UIFont (BoldVariant)

- (UIFont *)boldVariant
{
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:self.familyName]) {
        if ([fontName hasSuffix:@"-Bold"]) {
            return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:self.pointSize];
        }
    }

    // If we couldn't find it, return the same font.
    return self;
}

@end
```

This assumes that the font follows the standard naming scheme.  It also assumes that `fontNamesForFamilyName:` returns any values.  I noticed that with the system font, it returns an empty array.

Comment: Thanks! That works really well, and thank you for including the sample code. What I ended up doing is returning the bold system font if nothing was found, which also covers the case when the font is a system font to begin with and the array is empty:   return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.pointSize];

Answer (score 0):

If you are using for example system font which is Helvetica you can make the label.text bold like this:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
```

You can find iOS fonts for example in this site: [link](http://iosfonts.com)

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to avoid, as I want the flexibility of using it with any label and I want to be able to change fonts in the IB designer without having to then search for matching code changes. But thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You want an approach that works regardless of the font that is in place in your label, so it works with multiple labels?

How about this?

Fetch the current font from the label using it's font property.

Get the font family name for that font.

Ask the font family for it's list of fonts using the UI fontNamesForFamilyName.

See if you can find a bold font in the list of fonts you get back. If so, request that font at your current font size. If not, use the bold system font at the current size. (You might have to string parse the font names looking for the word "bold" in the name. Ugh.)

Not ideal, but you should be able to make it work.

Comment: heh yeah that's kind of what I was thinking too, but it seems so clunky to be looking for the word "bold". I was hoping there would be a way to get details about a font that would indicate it was the bold variant. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find nice and clear solution:

```
extension UIFont {

    /// Returns same font but with specific `symbolicTraits`.
    func with(symbolicTraits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont {
        let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(symbolicTraits) ?? fontDescriptor
        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: pointSize)
    }
}
```

Usage:

`label.font = label.font.with(symbolicTraits: .traitBold)`

Or if you want to mix multiple traits:

`label.font = label.font.with(symbolicTraits: [.traitBold, .traitItalic)` // returns same font (name and size) but is bold and italic.